# Arduino LED brightness switching using pushbutton

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, c, software

I'm trying to switch between 4 different brightness of an LED using an Arduino Uno. I've used analogWrite and not digitalWrite with PWM. The problem i'm facing is that the brightness does not switch at all when the pushbutton is pressed.
Here's my code:

```
#define led 11 //assign pin 11 to LED
#define BUTTON 7 //assign pin 7 to pushbutton
int val=0; //val used to check current status of pushbutton later in the program
int old_val=0; //old_val to check previous status
int state=0; //state to check button presses

void setup()
{
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTON,INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  val=digitalRead(BUTTON); //check status of pushbutton
  if((val==HIGH)&&(old_val==LOW)) //button pressed
  {
    state++; //increment state
    delay(10); //debounce consideration
    if(state>4) //want only 4 brightness options
    {
      state=1;
      delay(10);
    }
  }
  old_val=val;
  if(state==1)
  {
    analogWrite(led,0); //0 brightness
  }
  else if(state==2)
  {
    analogWrite(led,75);
  }
  else if(state==3)
  {
    analogWrite(led,150);
  }
  else if(state==4)
  {
    analogWrite(led,255);
  }
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Does your push button automatically switch back after releasing it?

Comment: Yes it does. Instead of switching to the next brightness, it goes back to the same brightness.

Comment: #define led 11 //assign pin 11 to LED
this is wrong as long as you use analog , this can be from 0-5 .

Comment: I thought pins 1 to 5 serve only as analog INPUTS. Are you sure about it?

Comment: yes I'm sure it is for input and output .

Comment: You *can* use pin 11 for PWM! In fact, you can use any pin marked with a "~" for PWM on the Arduino Uno. The reference page for AnalogWrite (http://arduino.cc/de/Reference/AnalogWrite) confirms that too.

Answer (score 4):

Although your code has some weaknesses it shouldn't generate the behavior you describe. You haven't provided any shematic of the setup so my answer is really just a guess but a missing pull-down resistor would probably cause exactly what you're telling : the digital reading of the button pin sporadically switches between HIGH and LOW, and the led appears to flicker randomly instead of just changing brightness as expected.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I just realized there's no pull down resistor in my circuit. Will revert back when I'm able to add one.

Comment: The AVR that the arduino is based on has internal pull up resistors. It is much easier to use the switch to connect to ground and have the internal pullup resistors enabled.

Comment: To enable the internal pullup set the pin mode as `INPUT_PULLUP` instead of `INPUT`

Answer (score 0):

```
#define led 11 //assign pin 11 to LED
#define BUTTON 7 //assign pin 7 to pushbutton
#define SAMPLING 250 //250milliSecond per press, used for debouncing

static unsigned long TIMER = 0; //record current millis()
byte state = 0; //val used to check current status of pushbutton later in the program
byte brightness[] = {0, 75, 150, 255}; //comment this out if not picky  

void setup()
{
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BUTTON,INPUT);
  digitalWrite(BUTTON, HIGH); //use internal pull up resistor, no need for external resistor   
}

void loop()
{
  if(millis() - TIMER >= SAMPLING) //sampling ~= 250mS
  {  
    TIMER = millis();
    if(!digitalRead(BUTTON)) //button pressed, pulled low
    {
      state++; //increment state
      if(state > 3) //want only 4 brightness options, 0, 1, 2, 3
        state = 0;
      analogWrite(led, brightness[state]); //if you aren't picky, use analogWrite(led, state*85); 
                                           //no byte array;
                                           //0*85 = 0
                                           //1*85 = 85
                                           //2*85 = 170
                                           //3*85 = 255
    }
  }
}
```